Logger messages do not appear in expected order when used with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor
In:
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def thread_function(name):
    # logging.info("Thread %s: starting", name)
    print(f'Thread {name}: starting')
    time.sleep(2)
    print(f'Thread {name}: finishing')
    # logging.info("Thread %s: finishing", name)


def hello(i):
    time.sleep(i)
    print(i)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%H:%M:%S")

    logging.info('Before tpe')

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        result = executor.map(thread_function, range(3))


    logging.info('After tpe')

    print('out here')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('out there')

The logger does not produce messages in the expected order while print does. With logging the messages Before tpe and After tpe are interleaved with the ones in thread_function.
This shouldn't be the case. Can the logger be used to display messages in the expected order? the order should only change in between runs inside thread_function but the messages before and after the executor should always be in the same positions (before/after)
The problem was using logger with print() at the same time. Using only the logger produces the expected result:
22:34:33: Before tpe
22:34:33: Thread 0: starting
22:34:33: Thread 1: starting
22:34:33: Thread 2: starting
22:34:35: Thread 1: finishing
22:34:35: Thread 0: finishing
22:34:35: Thread 2: finishing
22:34:35: After tpe
22:34:35: out here
22:34:38: out there

Interleaving the logger with printf produces different outputs:
Changing the last lines from:
logging.info('out here')
time.sleep(3)    
logging.info('out there')

to
print('out here')
time.sleep(3)
print('out there')

sometimes produces:
14:24:38: Before tpe
14:24:38: Thread 0: starting
14:24:38: Thread 1: starting
14:24:38: Thread 2: starting
out here
14:24:40: Thread 0: finishing
14:24:40: Thread 1: finishing
14:24:40: Thread 2: finishing
14:24:40: After tpe
out there


Please fix code formatting and add the output that you are getting and what you expect instead.

Sry, what is the expected result? I didn't get it from the question.

@Mark Tolonen & Johnny Cheesecutter The problem was using print() with logger (print() is faster). Using only logger produces the expected result

You are expecting order where there is none.

Your code as shown using print gives me the same result as the "only logger" output shown, even if I remove the long sleeps.  Are you saying you were getting Before tpe after one or more of the "Thread" messages?  Show the result you get when it isn't working and give more information about the environment (OS, IDE if any).  It could be possible that print flushes before logger.info since you are mixing output methods.

@Mark Tolonen yep. Updating question with outputs

can't reproduce (100's of iterations using logger or print .... python 3.12.4 on macos ), what's your h/ware/os/versions ...

@ticktalk ASUS Zenbook 15, Win 10, x64, python 3.6
